# Should 304 Not Modified responses include the "Last Modified" header?

Tags: apache2, http, http-headers, proxy

I've been using the most excellent http://redbot.org tool for testing have HTTP headers on my site correct (its custom code in PHP serving dynamic content - wanting to ensure it cached where possible - served by Apache2)

One of the tests says:

```
The If-Modified-Since response is missing required headers

HTTP requires 304 Not Modified responses to have certain headers, if they are also present in a normal (e.g., 200 OK response).
This response is missing the following headers: last-modified.
This can affect cache operation; because the headers are missing, caches might remove them from their cached copies.
```

... so resonse doesnt include the Last-Modified header. However the code does try to send it. Investigating further, it seems that Apache uses a whitelist of HTTP headers, it will allow on 304 responses...

```
if (r->status == HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED) {
    apr_table_do((int (*)(void *, const char *, const char *)) form_header_field,
                 (void *) &h, r->headers_out,
                 "Connection",
                 "Keep-Alive",
                 "ETag",
                 "Content-Location",
                 "Expires",
                 "Cache-Control",
                 "Vary",
                 "Warning",
                 "WWW-Authenticate",
                 "Proxy-Authenticate",
                 "Set-Cookie",
                 "Set-Cookie2",
                 NULL);
}
else {
    send_all_header_fields(&h, r);
}
```

This is found around line 1281 in modules/http/http_filters.c of the Apache HTTPD 2.2.22 source code.

.... "Last-Modified" is not on that list.

**So the question is - which is wrong, redbot, or Apache?**

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
doesn't seem to specify if the Last-Modified should be included. (it does say the Etag should be - and that is allowed in Apaches list)

Just incase its useful, this is the test case:
http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geograph.org.uk%2Fhelp%2Fsitemap
- my code does include the Last-Modified header - its just that redbot never gets it (nor any custom X-.. headers).

Comment: Why would the `Not Modified` response need a `Last-Modified` header? I can't think of any use cases where this would be required. If you're getting a 304, then you already fetched a previous copy and know the last-modified date, which hasn't changed since then.

Comment: that is pretty much the question. But redbot suggests otherwise - which is what I am questioning. It seems the thinking is caches will update the headers of the 'stored' object with those in the 304 - and as the last modified is now missing, it will be lost from the cached object. -- I supose some testing is needed :) - its worth noting I've never observed any issue with 304s not including the header - 304s continue to be issued for the same object - its just that the advice of redbot suggets otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct. RED implemented the requirements from HTTPbis https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p4-conditional-18#section-4.1.

Normally, HTTPbis requirements are backwards-compatible with RFC2616 (i.e., they don't make implementations that were conformant to 2616 non-conformance now), but this change slipped through -- we'll be opening an issue to fix that, and in the meantime I'll change REDs requirements.

Comment: great thanks! Sorry i didnt find a more direct way to contact you!

Answer (score 3):

No, `Last-Modified` is not required, as you cited from RFC 2616. I've found this issue https://github.com/mnot/redbot/issues/61 in which they implemented the check for required headers. However, they stated in the issue that only "Date" was required, but the implementation was different (by mistake, I think).

Comment: Ah thanks for that - I failed to find the github project for redbot - otherwise probably would of posted this there. Have tried the Google Group - but its held for moderation. And GGroups has a known issue that group owners arent notified of pending messages :(